# Primefaces autocomplete (multiple), handle prepopulated items

Tags: ajax, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a very simple `autocomplete` (multiple) component (similar as the one in the PF showcase), allowing users to select items from dropdown list, and a `commandbutton` to save the values to database.

`@PostConstruct` method fetches the data and prepopulates them (if found) in the autocomplete component.

The problem is that the component seems have no control to those prepopulated items. For example, if I delete one by clicking the close icon, it disappears from the page, but the event object in neither `ValueChangeListener`, `SelectEventListener` (Ajax itemselect), nor `UnselectEventListener` (Ajax unselect) returns correct value, instead they all return null. I can only add new item(s) or delete those new added item(s). If I delete one of the prepopulated items, and then click save, all other prepopulated items will be gone.

How to handle (delete) prepopulated items in autocomplete ?

```
PF version 5.2
```

*bean.java*

```
private List<SomeObjs> selectedSomeObjs = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.selectedSomeObjs = SomeDb.getSavedSomeObjs();
}

public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Object oldVal = event.getOldValue(); // return prepopulated items
    Object newVal = event.getNewValue(); // return null, if delete one of the prepupulated items
}
```

*.xhtml*

```
<p:autoComplete id="auto" multiple="true"
            value="#{bean.selectedSomeObjs}"
            completeMethod="#{bean.autoComplete}" var="v"
            itemLabel="#{v.desc}" itemValue="#{v}" autocomplete="true" maxResults="15"
            minQueryLength="1" queryDelay="100" forceSelection="true" cache="true"
            valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChange}">
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{bean.objsList}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{bean.selectListener}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.unselectListener}"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Please state your PF version

Comment: Try a newer one please

Comment: Tested on PF6.0.0, still no luck.